# Flickering while using Puppeteer SSR for Angular

Tags: angular, puppeteer, server-side-rendering

This is my first post here. Sorry if it's not the right way to ask a question. Will try to be as clear as possible.

I am using Puppeteer for SSR with my Angular app. It's working fine and as expected. I have tried Angular Universal in the past but Puppeteer seems to be more friendly and slightly better for my need.

However, I am not able to get rid of the flicker. API data is reloaded after the application bootstraps. Is there a way to get rid of the flicker and avoid API call from browser when the data is already present in SSR output.

Comment: Hi, is that fixed.? am also facing same issue...